# JuiceUI - sharing across projects

Tags: juice-ui

Is there a known way to configure JuiceUI to exist in one Visual Studio Web Application project and reference it from another Web application?  We want a centralized location for all of our Web Application to use it instead of having to install the JUiceUI.dll and Scripts folder in every project.

Thanks